# how can I receive the media button broadcast

Tags: android, broadcast, headset

I make these codes in my service:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
intentFilter.setPriority(2147483647);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
```

And that's the Receiver

```
public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            playNext(); // play the next music
        }
    };
```

But I never receiver the broadcast, I don't know why.
And every time I tap on the headset, the below will show

I/MediaButtonIntentReceiver: handle action:android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
I/MediaButtonIntentReceiver: action = 1, repeatCount = 0, command = togglepause, keycode = KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK

Rocco is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to obtain permission：

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, when I click my headset, it will show I/MediaPlaybackService: handleIntent=com.miui.player.musicservicecommand, cmd=togglepause I/MediaPlaybackService: Nothing to play

Comment: Sometimes I can success, but only once, and it doesn't work for a while.

Comment: You are right, I solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one reciever in your class:
you register "broadcastReceiver", but named it "broadcastReceiver1*"

Comment: my fault, my code is broadcastReceiver1 , but for the reason to let us see, I change it to broadcastReceiver. I forget to change it.